# Algebraic proof that this set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is empty

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Consider the following inequalities:

$$\begin{array}{ll}
y \geq a  - 2x & (A) \\
y \leq a - b - x & (B)
\end{array}
$$
where $x \geq 0$, $y \geq 0$ and $2 \leq b \leq a < 2b$.

These inequalities define a subset of the $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Graphically, I'm able to prove that this set is empty as shown by the following picture:

[image]

In particular:

- Line (A) intersects $x$ axis at $x_A = a/2$, and $y$ axis at $y_A = a$.
- Line (B) intersects $x$ axis at $x_B = a-b$, and $y$ axis at $y_B = a-b$.

Since $2 \leq b \leq a < 2b$, then:

- The intersections on the $x$ axis are such that $x_B < x_A$. Indeed:
  $$a-b < a/2 \Rightarrow a/2 < b \Rightarrow a < 2b.$$
- The intersections on the $y$ axis are such that $y_B < y_A$. Indeed:
  $$a-b < a \Rightarrow b > 0.$$

Well, the geometric proof seems to work.

How can I write this fact in a purely algebraic way?

I guess it is very trivial, but I'm stuck on this point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to see it: Suppose $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2_{\geq 0}$ were in the intersection. So, by definition,

$$a - 2 x  \overset{(A)}{ \leq } y  \overset{(B)}{ \leq } a - b - x \implies b \leq x. $$

But then $(B)$ implies

$$y \leq a - b - x \leq a - 2 b < 0$$

since $a < 2b$. This contradicts $y \geq 0$.

Comment: good point, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(x,y)$ is in the intersection. Then we have both inequalities satisfied:

(A) $y\ge a-2x$  and  (B) $y\le a-b-x$.

In other words (A') $x\ge (a-y)/2$ and (B') $x\le a-b-y$.

So together we have $(a-y)/2\le a-b-y$. Solving for $y$ gives

$(y/2)\le (a/2)-b < 0$, as $a<2b$. Hence $y < 0$, a contradiction of the original $y \ge 0$ condition. Namely, if this point lies in the intersection, then it is in the part below the $x$-axis as it geometrically suggests.

Comment: good point, thanks a lot!